# how to update many2many list with value [ODOO 12]

Tags: python, odoo

```
duplicate_beneficiaries_ids = fields.Many2many("openg2p.beneficiary",string='Potential Duplicates')

def update():
    benf_ids = ['2','4']
    self.update({'duplicate_beneficiaries_ids': [(6, 0, {benf_ids})]})
```

http://www.odooninja.com/update-many2many-field/
It does not take list as arguments.
If i should use a dictionary what shall be the {key:value} pairs.

Comment: The link doesn't work, can you remove the `\\`?

Comment: http://www.odooninja.com/update-many2many-field/

Comment: Is there an error upon running? Paste it please. If not, can you give us the expected output and what happened instead?

Comment: @12944qwerty 
It raises type error.
```
{'duplicate_beneficiaries_ids': [(6, 0, {benf_ids})]})
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Why are you surrounding `benf_ids` with brackets?

Comment: @12944qwerty    So should i update it using loops??

Comment: What? What do you update? What for?

Comment: @12944qwerty   For updating many2many field duplicate_beneficiaries_ids,such that if any id's present in the field it raises validation error.

Comment: ok, Bu you never answered my previous question. _Why_ did you surround `benf_ids` with brackets?

Comment: @12944qwerty I want to pass the whole list such that if any multiple records exist of same fields i want pass their id's too
I receive it in an requests response array

Comment: But _why the brackets?_

Comment: I receive it in a response array to a passed request

Comment: Try removing the brackets

Comment: how should i pass multiple values for benf_ids in self.update?

Comment: `self.update({'duplicate_beneficiaries_ids': [(6, 0, benf_ids)]})`

Comment: As i said it does not take a list ,other than list how will i update it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `write()` method. And I think you should us `4` not `6` because `4` links the IDs whereas `6` creates new records entirely.

```
duplicate_beneficiaries_ids = fields.Many2many("openg2p.beneficiary",string='Potential Duplicates')

def update():
    benf_ids = ['2','4']
    self.write({'duplicate_beneficiaries_ids': [(4, bid) for bid in benf_ids]})
```

Comment: It gives syntax error:
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near ")"
self.write({'duplicate_beneficiaries_ids': [(4, [benf_ids])]})

Comment: @truthfool I've updated the answer. Give that a go.